# Uploading same application for different company

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application that is for common use like shopkeeper inventory entry system.

Now i want that i can use this application for different company with only logo and theme change.

Is it possible to upload this type of application (with same functionality) for different company with different apple enrollment membership.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as companies don't have problem.. apple won't mind... they're not going to check whether it already exists or not...

Answer (score 1):

You will need a different app id, and therefore bundle id, for each version of the app.  This is no matter how it is distributed, apart from source code.  You should also look into the business-to-business licensing options; I don't know if there are available yet.

TL;DR: yes.

Answer (score 0):

The Business-To-Business licensing is only available in the US, AFAIK.

You could also only put one app on the App Store, and make the theme and logo importable via an URL or text import.